# Gulp won't create a folder

Tags: gulp

A new folder 'temp' should be created when I make changes to styles.css file. Gulp is watching for file changes, and that works, but is not creating new 'temp' folder with 'styles' subfolder, or the new styles.css file which it should also create.

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
     return gulp.src('.app/assets/styles/styles.css').pipe(gulp.dest('.app/temp/styles'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    watch('./app/assets/styles/**/*.css', function() {
    gulp.start('styles');
});
```

What do I need to change to make this work?

Comment: Is the '.app' in line 2 a typo? (should be ./app ?)

Comment: You're right, I fixed that, but still not creating 'temp' folder.

Comment: Does it create it if you call the task 'styles'? (I mean, the watch part is not relevant to the question if it does work)

Comment: actually it's working now! I fixed typos and refreshed watching. That was it, thanks a lot!